# where is transaction date in transaction in AggCat?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

In the transaction xsd, I do not see any `transaction date` but for accounting purposes, that detail is essential. Is `userDate` or `availableDate` related to transaction date somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the query parameters of getAccountTransaction API, you'll see txnStartDate and txnEndDate are referring to posted date. It is available in the response too. That should be the correct date to consider.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0030_getaccounttransactions#Query_Parameters

PN- Please ignore all transactions which are in pending state.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/@api/deki/files/46/customercentral_1.wadl 
has the "accounts/{accountId}/transactions"for "getAccountTransactions":
It has the Transaction start date and the Transaction end date which should solve your purpose.